# equation solution with two variables, i've got the answer but not the way

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know from the board the solution is 6 but i have no doubt why
if `n`and `m`are integers what is the only solution for`m` with `x =-3`?
$$x^2+mx+n=0$$ 
How can i solve it i even have no `n` ?

The only possible value for x is -3

Comment: Does the question specify that the only solution is $x=-3$ or just that $x=-3$ is a solution?  In the second case the problem is incorrect because you could have $m=0,n=9$, for example.

Comment: only possible value for x is -3

Comment: @David Please add clarifications to the body of the question, rather than the comments.

Comment: Welcome to math Stack Exchange, David. You should edit your question to clarify that important point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a quadratic equation, which means that, when we factor our equation, we must produce a square. We also know that our values for x will always be the opposite of the values inside the factor. (For example, if our factoring gave us $(x+2)(x−5)$, our values for $x$ would be $−2$ and $+5$).

So, given that our only possible value for x is −3, our factoring must look like this:$(x+3)(x+3)$

Which will give us: $x^2+3x+3x+9 \Rightarrow x^2+6x+9$. If we lock at the position of the $m$ in $x^2+mx+n=0$, it stands in the place of the $6$

($6x \Rightarrow mx$)